# Is there a property of Telerik RadTreeView to collapse all children when a parent is collapsed?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using MVVM for a WPF app and I have a Telerik RadTreeView, and when I collapse a parent, I'd like to recursively collapse all children (and their children, etc) so that when I expand the parent again, I don't see any grandchildren, because all children are collapsed. Is there a property of the RadTreeView that Can accomplish this, or any relatively easy alternative way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled across this question searching for some other RadTreeView related topics.

Based on the current [Telerik RadTreeView Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreeview-how-to-expand-and-collapse-items.html):

> When you need to expand or collapse all the items recursively for a given item use the ExpandAll() and CollapseAll() methods of the RadTreeViewItem respectively. When you need to expand/collapse all the nodes in the tree use ExpandAll() and CollapseAll() methods of the RadTreeView.